# TabView does not change the view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have created a custom `TabView` that looks as follows:

[image]

and the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedItem: TabItemOption = .market
     
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
                VStack {
                    TabView(selection: $selectedItem){
                        MarketView().tag(TabItemOption.market.rawValue)
                        
                        InterestView().tag(TabItemOption.interest.rawValue)
                        
                        WalletView().tag(TabItemOption.wallet.rawValue)
                        
                    }.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                }
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    TabBar(tappedItem: $selectedItem)
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

For example, when I click on the second `TabBarItem` the view does not get changed. It always shows the `MARKET` view with `Hello Market` text in the middle of the screen.
However, the `tag` modifier is set to identify the view uniquely.

I have also checked if the variable `selectedItem` gets changed every time when different `TabBarItem` gets pressed and it changes the value properly corresponding what get pressed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using the `rawValue` in the `tag` but using the enum (not rawValue) as the `selectedItem`. Change the `selectedItem` type to use the `rawValue` as well. (like Int or String or whatever the `rawValue` of `TabItemOption` is)

Comment: Alternatively, you could remove `rawValue` from each `tag`.